# Sequentially run batch code

Tags: batch-file

Probably a really obvious question, I'm trying to run some sequential batch code to define my own eclipse external run configurations.

One of the calls in the .bat is to run a jetty server, and after this I want to launch a program. At the moment the execution of the .bat means that the call to run jetty hangs on that call, and the call to open the program is only executed once the jetty server has been killed.

Is there any way I can run the call to start jetty, and then immediately run another call to open any program that wont have to wait for the server to be killed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `start` to run a program in the background explicitly:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\etc.\blah\x.exe"
```

Execution of the batch file immediately continues after that line. In case of jetty you're probably starting Java anyway. `cmd` doesn't wait for GUI processes so you can also use

```
javaw -jar ...\jetty.jar
```

instead of calling `java`.

---

Since the question has changed a bit after the comment:

If there is a reliable way of knowing when jetty has started, e.g. a file that will exist somewhere

```
:l
timeout /t 1 >nul
if not exists %temp%\somefile goto l
```

you could use that. Otherwise you can just wait for a while

```
rem wait two minutes
timeout /t 120 > nul
```

and hope that everything has started by then.

Comment: I tried this, the trouble is, I dont want the program to be run until the jetty server has been started...but if I list this line of code after

"call mvn.bat -jettyArgsEtc"

it doesnt get run until the jetty server is terminated